# Tensorflow - displaying and manually modifying weights of learned model and exporting for further relearning

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

What I try to do with Tensorflow is as follows:

1. Consider I have learned neural network files: checkpoint, *.meta, *.data and *.index.
2. I want to extract learned values (weights, biases, ...) to be displayed or processed to file/other tool for further analysis.
3. I want to modify some of the learned values (for example replace with 0 some weights that are already of small value, to simplify the computation).
4. Modified values should be loaded back to model.
5. As a result, I would like to get same set of checkpoint, *.meta, *.data and *.index file, but with some modified values (from step 4).

Note: The script used to generate inital model is unknown. All I have in step 1 is 4 listed files.

What I managed to do so far is to extract graph definition and display learned values (with inspect_checkpoint.py). I find it impossible to change values ON model and export it back to set of *.data, *.meta, *.index and checkpoint. After going thru API I do not see obvious tools for such operations. Is it even possible?
Best regards and thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can read/write tensors from/to a checkpoint file using `CheckpointReader` and `BundleWriter`:

```
BundleWriter writer(tensorflow::Env::Default(), "out.ckpt");                                                                                                                                        

TF_Status status;                                                                                                                                                                                        
tensorflow::checkpoint::CheckpointReader reader("in.ckpt", &status);

const auto& var_to_shape_map = reader.GetVariableToShapeMap();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
for (const auto& elem : var_to_shape_map) {                                                                                                                                                              
  std::unique_ptr<Tensor> weights;                                                                                                                                                                       
  const string& key = elem.first;                                                                                                                                                                        
  reader.GetTensor(key, &weights, &status);  
  auto weights_flat = weights->flat<float>();
  for (int i = 0; i < weights->NumElements(); ++i) {
    // replace with 0 some weights that are already of small value
    if (weights_flat(i) < SMALL_VALUE_THRESHOLD) {
      weights_flat(i) = 0.f;
    }
  }
  writer.Add(key, *weights.get());                                                                                                                                                        
}
writer.Finish();
```

After running the above codes, you will get `out.ckpt.data` and `out.ckpt.index`.
You can use the original *meta file since we only modified the values of learned weights and the meta info remains unchanged.